# Uncaught exception from servlet java.io.IOException at app engine. 500 Server Error after running app second time

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I have just started with App Engine and I have tried to make a very simple app which adds Person objects with distinctive names to the datastore. This the object:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Person {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Persistent
@Unique
private String name;

public Person(String nameIn){
    this.name = nameIn;
}

public Long getId(){
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long idIn){
    this.id = idIn;
}
```

}

This servlet is responsible for persisting objects on datastore. But prior to that, the method `doesUserExist(String)` checks whether object with the same 'name' field exists:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PersonDatastoreServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final String PARAM_NAME = "name";
private PersistenceManager pmf = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {

        String name = req.getParameter(PARAM_NAME);
        PrintWriter printWriter  = response.getWriter();

        try{

            if(!doesUserExist(name)) {
                Person p = new Person(name);
                pmf.makePersistent(p);

                response.setContentType("text/html");
                printWriter.println("<h1>"+p.getId()+"</h1>");
            }
            else {
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                printWriter.println("<p>User already exists</p>");
            }   
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        finally{
            pmf.close();
        }
    }

private boolean doesUserExist(String nameIn) {

    Query q = pmf.newQuery(Person.class);
    q.setFilter("name == lastNameParam");
    q.declareParameters("String lastNameParam");

    String name = nameIn;

    try{
        List<Person> list = (List<Person>) q.execute(name);

        if (list.isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }
    finally{
        q.closeAll();
    }
}
```

}

The take seems very straightforward, but it just not working. I have a form which processing the request. When I run my app for the first time it does successfully create and persist an object, however whenever i want to add another object with a different name, I am getting the Error

```
Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.
```

It indicates that the query causes the problem but I have idea what is wrong with my query. Can anybody help please?

Comment: what query? you don't have one there. Please don't name a PersistenceManager "pmf", it will confuse the hell out of anyone reading it. What does the log say? object persisted? exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JDO - key value not being displayed after persisting the object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259371/jdo-key-value-not-being-displayed-after-persisting-the-object)